# Ban ImageShack Images

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, images, banning

ImageShack deletes images all the time. People looking for help on older questions / answers on Stack Exchange may find them confusing and hard to understand if the post contains an image which was automatically deleted from ImageShack.
Please, can we ban ImageShack (maybe by not allowing links to ImageShack somehow)?

Some good alternatives when images are needed are:

- **Preferable:** Use Stack Exchange's own imgur account for uploading (easily done with the "insert image"-button of the editor), thus keeping them available as long as Stack Exchange.
- http://www.imgur.com ([Does imgur delete old images that have few image views?](https://superuser.com/questions/887254/does-imgur-delete-old-images-that-have-few-image-views); Super User 10k+; [Archive of page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321212759/https://superuser.com/questions/887254/does-imgur-delete-old-images-that-have-few-image-views))
- http://www.postimage.org (Also pretty certain they don't delete old images)
- http://www.gyazo.com (Yes, it takes screenshots, but that's what lots of people need anyway)
- Others: http://alternativeto.net/software/imageshack/

At the moment, [there are over 5000 posts linking to imageshack on main](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aimageshack), and, many of them have been deleted by ImageShack.

[Here is a link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340339/posts-with-images-hosted-on-imageshack) to a search for embedded ImageShack images in questions / answers. If you sort by the creation date, you can see how many are missing (especially ones with 0 votes).

I am not quite sure on the mechanics of the deletion process, and if someone knows please comment below and maybe post a link to an article if one exists.

Comment: [I completely agree](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3058059/revisions)

Comment: Should we also change working imageshack links to SE's imgur before it's too late?

Comment: All images should be re-uploaded with SE's imgur account, though we should focus on imageshack first.

Comment: Besides, when an image is deleted, it becomes spam. Picking @durron597 's example, http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2809/capturelp.png

Comment: The search link you gave seems to mostly (only?) list posts linking to ImageShack using text links. For posts with embedded ImageShack images, see [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340339/posts-with-images-hosted-on-imageshack).

Comment: I stumbled upon some imageshack's deleted and now spam images and as a user it infuriates me. If I'm determined enough to get the post images I might try with google cache but most of the time I just stick with what I can read or try to find another question. I agree with this.

Comment: What's actually the problem with disallowing external images completely? Make the Stack Exchange upload available at zero rep and let the usual spam handling deal with any problems. I never upload externally, I see no need.

Comment: Why wouldn't you mention flickr?

Comment: @usr: You can put up a new feature request for that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen added

Comment: BTW, note that the limit of 1000 posts returned by the SEDE query is artificial, to avoid timeouts. Here's a [variant of the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340417/posts-with-images-hosted-on-imageshack-and-10-score) that only shows matching posts with 10+ score; there are a bit under 500 of those. I'm not sure how high the total number is, but I'd guess at least 10,000.

Comment: @OddDev - IIRC Flickr used to be a little weird about people embedding images. The current code they give you to do this includes a script tag.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more. Any posts with images hosted there will be damaged if the image "goes offline."

Comment: Imageshack is no longer a free image host. Now you have to pay to upload images, so they won't be deleting people's images any more any time soon.

Comment: @desbest Still, there is a 30-day free trial user may use. But that's good news

Comment: The post is **fine here**. There is no need to migrate or re-post.

Comment: Photobucket is no good, it deletes images all the time.

Comment: Why not just automatically upload all non-imgur images to imgur automatically?

Comment: ImageShack **used** to be ok. There's no guarantee imgur or the others won't suddenly "go bad" like they did.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's why SE's own imgur account is probably the best

Comment: We should probably just ban any images not uploaded through stackoverflows image button since it cannot be guaranteed that the destination of the image is a reputable one, for one...

Comment: @usr - maybe if we could change the zero rep thing to be a big red notice "you're about to attach an image. If it's an image of code, please be aware that there are better ways of sharing code with us, and we can't copy and paste images onto our machines to try out your code" then links of to the help pages, etc. Because the number of times a zero rep user has complained about not being able to upload images of their code has... surprised me.

Comment: Man, I remember when ImageShack was the "new, good, free place" to host images and direct-link to them forever after having to deal with Photobucket for far too long. I hope Imgur sticks around for a bit longer.

Comment: I'm also not a fan of external imagehosting at all so you get an *YES, but* from me. *But*? Because on mobiles you don't have the possibilty to use the image upload from SE as there is no editor. The only chance to post an image (e.g. on meta for bug report) are external image hoster. This should be kept in mind as long there is no image upload feature for mobiles.

Comment: @TylerH: It's always a cycle. Sites come and go. When they come we think they're awesome because some other sites recently went. It'll never change. :)

Comment: @bish You can add photos from a mobile device.  Click on the full site link and you get the full text editor.  When you click on the image upload button you can click on the text in the popup that says `click here`.  That will allow you to upload images from your mobile device.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's a workaround though, and not a particularly good one at that. This all being said I still don't understand the attraction of using SO "on the go", so whatever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes but at least you can still use the SE imgur account.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess I'm saying I'd also want that to be resolved if non-SE-imgur images were banned. Doesn't seem quite right, otherwise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally agree with that.  Personally I fell the mobile site is lacking in the editor and not having auto complete in `@username` in comments.  That part really irks me as I am more likely to go to my PC to answer but I do comment from my phone.

Comment: Can't people with enough rep use SE imgur, and people without enough rep improve the grammar or formatting of five posts and then use SE imgur?

Comment: Why does SE not just host images itself? They have money now, surely they can afford the bandwidth.

Comment: Can someone bump this? Nothing has been done.

Comment: "ImageShack used to be ok." Yes back when it was the *only* free image hosting solution out there (that didn't require registration)... it was "ok."

Comment: By this logic, why do we allow any external images? The web is ephemeral.

Answer (score 88):

The situation is now much worse. ImageShack is not only deleting old images, it's reusing some of the deleted image URLs for advertisements. I just had to edit the images out of [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22146/211113) different [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43904/211113) the same [Meta Stack Exchange thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/stickers-for-stackers-i-e-post-your-sticker-shots):

[image: Example]

I think it's very important that these should be removed across the entire network.

Comment: So *that's* their latest trick. Good thing we have imgur these days.

Comment: Oh my god, I got this problem too in my own website.
Moving to imgur right now :(

Comment: This business model is disgusting. Plain and simple.

Comment: If you thought it couldn't get any worse - it did. They are using those links to promote Putin's regime now.

Answer (score 42):

**UPDATE (October 9):** We've received 6 images from ImageShack since the warning has been in place (and 2 of them were edited in after the fact, so they didn't see the warning). We've also made some improvements to the image uploader so it's more usable for new users. We'll keep an eye on this, but I'll mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for now.

We now display a warning when users attempt to embed or link to an ImageShack image:

[image: imageshack warning]

Comment: Why a warning and not an entire block? This doesn't seem a solution to me.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Let's give it some time and track how many images we get from ImageShack (I think we've had ~0.5 a day since the warning has been in place). Do note I haven't marked this as [tag:status-completed] at this time.

Comment: I agree with Patrick Hofman, it would be better to entirely ban images from Imageshack. Also, the warning only shows up on Stack Overflow, if I try to post Imageshack images on Super User it doesn't tell me anything. I think that the ban (or warning) should exist on all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @DonaldDuck if you feel strongly about this, I recommend opening a new question on meta: this one is 2 years old, and I no longer work at Stack Overflow anyway, so there's nothing I can do about your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I do agree that this is something that should be fixed.  But lets look at it on a more large scale, there are lots of services that do this aside from ImageShack, I can think of two good solutions here.

1. Automatically port images from other resources to StackExchange's Imgur.
2. Disallow users from using images that are not via StackExchange's Imgur.

As far as #1 goes, I'm not so sure how hard that'd be to implement, so #2 wouldn't be so bad of an alternative.

My main driving point behind implementing this feature is to preserve questions' images for future users.  It would stop a lot of confusion, and I personally have also encountered a few questions like this, and it's pretty frustrating.

So, +1

*`EDIT:`* As far as your alternative services go, I see no reason not to force or port images to our own.  We already have it and it's ours, so lets stick with that.

Comment: For #1, I'm not sure (because I'm not a lawyer), but there may be legal concerns for porting the images automatically.

Comment: In the uploading panel, it is mentioned that any images uploaded with it are licensed under CC (attribution required), so you do bring up a good point.  Perhaps #1 isn't a valid option at all.

Comment: As the whole post is subject to CC license, any embedded image has to be too, no matter where its stored - at least in German jurisdiction. Images that are only linked but not embedded don't need to be as the observant can clearly tell that they are leaving the current place when they hit a link. So I see no legal problem with forbidding embedded images to other sites.

Comment: Potential solution #2 will have to be very carefully adapted to the situation of new posters who do not have enough reputation to embed images directly into their question. It is crucial to still let new posters be allowed to link to images, even we don't allow them to embed images directly from their question/answer.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs, I am not a lawyer, but in the US, the case law seems to be quite different than in Germany. The Ninth Circuit held that Google did not violate the provisions of the copyright law prohibiting reproduction and distribution of copies of a work: "Because Google's computers do not store the photographic images, Google does not have a copy of the images for purposes of the Copyright Act."