# Okay to edit just to delete images?

Tags: discussion, edits

As stated on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300232/ban-imageshack-images), ImageShack deletes old images. When we find posts that include links to deleted ImageShack images (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167512/java-socket-port-forwarding)), what should we do? Is it okay to edit and delete those links?

Also, is it okay to edit a question just to move images hosted by ImageShack to something more permanent, like imgur?

Comment: Absolutely Though, I'd rather you replace the links with something more permanent, than delete them outright. Lots of posts with images depend on their inclusion.  I'd say it's a good idea to replace ImageShack hosted images with the SO imgur account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even after deletion the original links are still available in the revision history but I wouldn't remove it completely.

I would try:

- to leave a comment for the OP to inform them that their post lost value, and/or;
- to find the post in the Wayback machine to recover the image (tried that for the example post, but no luck), and/or;
- Edit the post to remove the links if the post doesn't loose value without them, and/or;
- down vote if the post becomes useless without the images.

If you (or the OP) did find/recreated the image the best thing is to upload it to Stack Exchange's Imgur by using the Image icon in the toolbar.

Comment: What if the post is old (like years old)

Comment: Does it matter? If the OP isn't seen for years my first suggestion is likely not going to be successful but otherwise I see no reason to handle old stuff very much different then new stuff that has broken links/links to off-site value.