# Asked to review edit on a really old question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

In my review queue was a recent edit to a question from 2008.
Should this be happening?
Shouldn't it just be considered out-of-date by now?
What's the use of editing questions that are more than a couple of years old?

Comment: What if there's new information, or someone looking today at an old question and wanting to edit it?

Comment: Did you mean **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9360129)** ? The proposed date is of today.

Comment: @Shaunak, the date of the original Q is 2008!

Comment: @Octopus And the link fix was edited in today, hence it appeared in the edit review queue.

Comment: It's not like the old answer isn't useful anymore, it's just...old.  Edits can improve these by (at the minimum) updating links that are broken.  Who knows, some poor sap may be stuck supporting this *exact* scenario; who are we to deprive them of a useful resource?

Comment: I'm not questioning the fact that the edit was made today. Links will die with age. That's a given. Are we expected to go and fix all old links from 2008?

Comment: And besides, isn't this the reason why link only answers are discouraged. The meat of the answer should be in the body.

Comment: If you can, please do.  But I wouldn't say fix ***all*** of them since that's a huge undertaking, and a [well-known problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them) in these parts.  But if you happen across an answer and you know you can improve it, feel encouraged to.

Comment: @Octopus You're certainly not expected to do so, but some people stumbling over that and fix it correctly are surely welcome.

Answer (score 11):

> Should this be happening?

Yes

> Shouldn't it just be considered out-of-date by now?

No

> What's the use of editting questions that are more than a couple of years old?

To improve or correct grammatical, formatting, spelling, and other mistakes.

To update with new information that wasn't available back then.

To update with better information than what was originally given, even though that same info has been available for long time.

Most good questions/answers aren't totally obsolete. Most are still very relevant if not the correct way to do something today.

There is no close reason on SO for "obsolete" for a reason, even though the question may appear obsolete to you and others, does not mean someone else won't find it helpful.

We don't want people editing old questions incorrectly by adding wrong information, nonsense, spam, trolling, etc, etc, so that's why we still review those suggested edits.

Comment: I agree.  In the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), it even recommends editing  "_To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages._"