# janeg.ca links now directs to domain sale, and spawns nasty popups

Tags: discussion

I was reading a question and clicked on a link to a `janeg.ca` page (don't try it) that ended up spawning popups galore, including sending me to `algoprime.co`. It seems that janeg.ca is now dead (and for sale).

There are a number of java answers that link to janeg.ca ([google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=site:stackoverflow.com%20linkto:www.janeg.ca)), although the question I was on is not in that list <strike>and I can't see it in my browser history</strike> (it was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3741773/1945631)).

How do we quickly and easily find and disable all links to janeg.ca pages?

Comment: Well, there are only 48 posts linking to them on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ajaneg.ca

Comment: @Deduplicator - do you think there is a need for an internal SO function to do a large scale search/delete for dead links like this? I replaced that one with a WaybackMachine version, but that took me a while due to the speed of my connection.

Comment: When it's something large-scale but easily automated, a CM or dev sometimes does it. Otherwise, it's a manual task.

Comment: @Deduplicator - in terms of process, would one tag each question with, say, dead-link, and then burn through them all, removing each one's tag as it is done?

Comment: Why two edits where one suffices?

Comment: @Deduplicator, ah, I was thinking about the time involved in finding a wayback equivalent for the link. If it is just a case of employing <strike>`strike`</strike> then, yes, one would suffice. Which should we be doing?

Comment: Why would you have to mark any of the affected posts first?

Comment: @Deduplicator  - scaling. If it takes me 4 minutes to find the appropriate Wayback replacement, and there are 48 of them, that's 3 hours of thankless editing time that I don't have, not to mention disconnects and resuming and working out where I left off. If it takes 20 seconds to mark them as `[dead-link]`, that's "only" 15 minutes, and a permanent marker so others can tackle *any* `[dead-link]` questions/answers as well. Downside to that, now I say it out loud, is the tag applies to the question and doesn't highlight the damaged answer.

Comment: I suppose each answer could be flagged for mod attention, but that feels like overkill for a task any editor could do.

Comment: Seems what you want is a new review-queue for dead links. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them As-is, do as many as you can and want to do, and leave the rest for others.