# Dead links to deleted "bad" questions/answers from meta make it hard to learn SO best practices

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, deleted-questions

Many times, reviewing meta questions in order to learn more about what makes a good/bad SO question or practice (e.g., should I provide a good answer to a bad question), the link from the meta question to the question's target question (or answer) leads to a deleted question.

This makes it hard to learn the best practices by example (i.e., by example to the bad practices). (Especially as many answers/comments on meta are really quite specific and have discussion of pros/cons that are directly related to the target's questioner or answerer doing or writing or behaving in particular way.)

EDIT: Here's an example I just hit [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)]

So: Perhaps links from meta to deleted questions could still show the question.  Perhaps the question shown could be "sanitized" of users (the questioner, the answerers, etc) and maybe even of comments.  But show enough of it so that the meta question still has a useful example to refer to.

Comment: Can you give some examples? I'm not sure learning from bad examples is a good approach, given all the documentation around what to do and what not to do.

Comment: I'll see if I can just retrace my steps.  I asked this question because I just hit it twice on two different meta questions I was looking at.

Comment: Downvote because "doesn't show research effort, is unclear, or not useful"?  Which?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - yes there's lots of documentation, but also, "hot meta posts" show in the sidebar.  I look at interesting ones, and especially the upvoted and/or accepted answers, and treat them as additional documentation around what to do and what not to do.  Why else feature meta posts on a low-rep user's pages (like mine)?

Comment: @davidbak Downvotes on Meta often mean "I don't agree with [something you proposed in your question]" rather than the question being unclear or useless. Feature requests in particular are subject to this. It's just how Meta is. It won't affect your reputation.

Comment: @Louis - thanks! I forgot about that (this is my first actual meta post).

Comment: Well, in that question the one referred to on the main site as an example is not actually that important, it's just an example and (unless it is disputed) you can simply take the OP's characterization of it at face-value. Having it available won't really teach you anything more. (Anyway, [rene](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) added a screenshot.)

Comment: [Required reading about voting here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant - good link - maybe the tooltip on the down arrow on the question on meta should have a hot link to that post! :-)

Comment: Well you would have to follow the directions in that post to make such a request and have it well received `:)`

Answer (score 7):

[Link rot is a common problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them) not only on the main site but to some extent on meta as well.

Links to external resources should only be complementary to the post and that is also true for links form meta to questions that are now deleted.

There has been attempts to [automate this link rot detection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/what-happened-to-the-broken-link-review-queue) and fix this but they either failed or didn't reach their goal. I admit that your suggestion to fix this for Stack Overflow posts isn't an insane idea but I rather propose to fix this in a similar way we should fix all posts with broken links:

- ping the OP that their link is dead
- try to locate the content yourself
- Just remove the link / mark it as deleted if it is not important.
- edit the relevant content from the link in the post
- for links to deleted posts: ask a >10K-er to provide a screenshot (as I did for the post you linked to)
- down vote

Although this is meta, there is no reason to have much different quality rules. Adjusting the policy for who can see questions if they are referred from meta is not something that is needed to be implemented.

Comment: Related analysis of link rot on the main site: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them

Comment: I understand what you're saying - but it isn't really link rot in this particular instance, is it?  I understand that users with sufficiently high rep can see the deleted posts.  So they're still there.  This is more of a policy/access decision to not allow the post to be visible.  I'm just suggesting, that in the case of meta, that policy be adjusted.  (But thanks for the screenshot!)

Comment: It is link rot based on your rep. And I understand your suggestion, I don't think it needs to be implemented and I try to express the reasons for that in my answer.

Comment: "not an insane idea" - that's the bar I shoot for!