# We need a way to deal with deprecated web links and external resources

Tags: feature-request, link-only-answers, hyperlinks, broken-link, external-links

I have encountered this issue many times:

- You search for hours for an answer to your question
- Finally find a great answer
- The answer only contains a snapshot or less with an external link to the complete solution
- The linked resources are no longer there

I would like a way for Stack Overflow to keep a PDF copy (or any type of copy) of every linked external resource, this way knowledge won't get lost.

Comment: *Finally find a great answer* If the answer relies on a link to give you the answer it is not a great answer.

Comment: If you have a URL, the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/index.php) might be able to help you find the original content behind the link. If it does, please use it improve the existing answer.

Comment: *The answer only contains a snapshot or less with an external link to the complete solution* If there isn't enough information to answer the question, flag it as "Not An Answer". It doesn't help with your immediate problem but at least the next person doesn't get their hopes up.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them

Answer (score 10):

While I can sympathize with the idea, saving an copy of all external resources is practically impossible to implement. That's never going to happen.

Currently, info in answers should be sufficient, in case not a single link in there works any more.
Links are nothing more than additional optional information.

Answers that require someone to read the contents of a link are incomplete. If possible, they should be improved so the answer is still valid if the link dies.

Comment: A way of saving external resources has been suggested in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/301001/1677912); poke it into the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/). A little outside-the-box, but feasible. (Until archive.org ip-bans SO! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cerbrus [hit part of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321465/2348587) with storage issues, but your request would also be terribly illegal.

You can't just download the internet and serve it back up from your servers. Those sites have a copyright to their content. The only reason quoting partial content on SO is ok is because it is considered Fair Use.

Comment: Meh, if it's for educational purposes we could argue the whole archive is fair use.