# Is it helpful to edit dead links to Internet Archive links?

Tags: discussion, edits, broken-link

I recently found an answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233579/can-i-build-a-website-for-china-on-heroku-hosting) question that has a dead link in it. I thought about changing the link to the one on Internet Archive ([here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130302031946/http://ragusource.com/blog/post/2012-05-22-how-to-stop-sites-from-being-blocked-in-china)) but didn't know if it was a legitimate edit.

**My reasoning for changing the link:**

1. If I change the link, future readers can access it easier.

**My reasons for NOT changing the link:**

2. The link is dead because it is outdated, which won't be helpful to
   other people.

What should I do?

Comment: A quick edit is often a better notification than a comment about a broken link. (It should be noted though that internet archive links don't last for eternity either.)

Comment: I was the last person to approve your edit. I also flagged the comment, so everything is cleaned up now.

Comment: `The link is dead because it is outdated, which won't be helpful to other people.`  You should not assume that because a link is dead that the information is dated or irrelevant.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, please edit the post to fix the link. Broken links are one of the main reasons so-called ['link-only' answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) are often deleted, so fixing them is highly encouraged. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them) for some statistics about this topic.

If the link itself is outdated, you should either leave a comment stating this, or (while you're editing the post) add a remark about this in the post itself. The latter *could* get your suggested edit rejected, because people might interpret it as a reply to the answerer, instead of an (IMHO) valid edit. Both actions would preserve the original intent of the answerer.

Comment: But even if you fix the broken link of a link-only answer, it will still be a link-only answer.

Comment: The relevant content should always be edited into the post. Updating the link is only a little bonus in my opinion