# How to handle edits containing Web Archive links

Tags: discussion, broken-link

I've been seeing edits to links, changing the URL to point to a [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org) snapshot, presumably because the original link no longer works.

Is updating links to point to a Web Archive snapshot a preferred long-term solution for dead links?

In this [specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path/23400088#23400088), the link is within an answer with a score of +14, (trailing another answer with a score of +50). There is no accepted answer. Also, the answer contains a description to be relevant without the link, so the link could be removed and the answer remain relevant.

[image]

Comment: That is what I use to fix dead URLs.  It is dead as a doornail, redirecting to a realtor site.  These are good edits.

Comment: I usually try to find a new place where this content was moved and lives now. If there is no such place, then there is an option to use Web Archive. But I'm not sure if it is ok.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327814/is-it-helpful-to-edit-dead-links-to-internet-archive-links