# Fix broken links to external Guava documentation

Tags: discussion, broken-link

At some point [guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guava) documentation was moved from

> `http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/`

to

> `http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/`.

There are answers that are using the old link, but they are providing enough information from the docs in such a way that makes the documentation access almost optional (I'm sure that this is not always the case, but I haven't found an answer like this yet).
I saw users (myself included) that updated the broken links, but I think that it happen when those answers were found by someone.

Is there a way to fix this automatically or a collective effort should be made in order to fix them?

Maybe we should let them as they are and hope that somebody fixes them when that answer is used, or not fix them at all?

I'm not really sure how this should be handled because the [community has different opinions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them) on how we should deal with broken links.

Comment: my search returns close to [500](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdocs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com%2Fgit-history%2Frelease%2Fjavadoc%2F) posts.

Comment: Cool feature, I didn't know that you can search for an url in posts!

Comment: I guess the Stack Exchange team could perform a batch action like that, as they did when all sites migrated to HTTPS. But the discussion may be if that's worth it for ~500 posts

Comment: This is far from trivial to implement. I think it'd be more reliable to manually change these links...

Comment: Either "haven't found" or "didn't find." But definitely not "didn't found."

Comment: @jpmc26 I fixed the error. Now regarding the edit process: do you think that users with at least 2k reputation should make the edits (in order to skip the review queue) or anyone should try to take part in it?

Comment: Dunno, but I think editing a bunch of existing posts to permanently link to a specific version is probably ill advised. Is there a "latest" link or something?

Comment: @IulianPopescu Along with changing the links, we should also try to fix all of the content and formatting errors. ***This goes for all users***. But mainly when <2k users edit, you must at least make an attempt to fix other problems of the post. Otherwise the edit might appear too trivial to reviewers and get rejected in the review queue.

Comment: Maybe we could use the snapshot instead of the version number in order to show the latest release? On Github they say: `Snapshots of Guava built from the master branch are available through Maven using version HEAD-jre-SNAPSHOT, or HEAD-android-SNAPSHOT for the Android flavor.`

Comment: Forgot to mention, the url looks like this: `http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/`