# Can we fix dead Flutter documentation links?

Tags: discussion, support

There are many questions/answers where Flutter's documentation links are old and dead. These links start with `docs.flutter.io`, whereas the new URLs should start with `api.flutter.dev`.

An example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034480):

Outdated link: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html

New link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/automaticallyImplyLeading.html

There are many questions and answers like this. Is there a way to migrate all of them at once? Or should I just hit Edit and update the links when I see these links.

Comment: You could also find a couple more examples and post this on the relevant Flutter support forum. If it's the same pattern for all the links in the older URLs, they could automatically redirect the old links to the new format

Comment: @Nimantha I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate of that question as the staff have a tool to do such URL substitutions as noted in this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367881/links-to-html-versions-of-rfcs-need-to-move-from-tools-to-datatracker

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Noted! (voted to reopen). Also found a couple of related posts: 1) No answers: [Fix broken links to external Guava documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361911/fix-broken-links-to-external-guava-documentation) 2) With an answer: [MSDN blog links are broken, what should we do now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394045/msdn-blog-links-are-broken-what-should-we-do-now)

Comment: [Cool URLs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)... just sayin'