# What are the correct steps to perform, when finding dead and rotten links?

Tags: discussion, edits, broken-link

157 links to Tech.pro/ are dead and rotten. They are redirecting to various fake support and other malicious ads.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+tech.pro%22

I don't have the edit power to fix them without flooding the review queue.
Most of the answer I reviewed were link only or not worthy.

What are the correct steps when finding these kinds of dead and rotten links?

Comment: Edit. Replace with archived versions from the internet archive, or outright remove them. It's probably better done by 2k users though

Comment: Well will try to script the url parsing from So, and link from InternetArchive in order to ease the process. But for comment I won't be able to edit them. It will require some mighty power.

Comment: I tried two and you need to go back a few captures in the wayback machine. It looks like that site went "inactive" first for a year or so, before it was "hijacked"

Comment: @xdtTransform you can mod-flag comments. A NLN flag will probably be declined because it's context-dependent

Comment: Use the `url:` search modifier: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=url%3Atech.pro. That's 366 hits. Then perhaps start reducing the list to just, say, only answers with `is:a` or only questions with `is:q`. Etc.

Comment: Next, for posts that are perhaps worth salvaging, see if there is an Internet Archive copy, by prefixing the URL with `https://web.archive.org/web/*/<url>` and seeing what comes up. Pick the archived copy closest to the date that the post was made, then suggest an edit fixing the link by replacing it with the archived version.

Comment: I've dealt with the negatively-scored 'answers' already, so there are a few posts less now.

Comment: Made an Edit link + Web archive link for the 408 match I got on Sede . Will htmlparse the result with url: search modifier to see if I missed any. And will add one answer for comment, if there is to mutch for manual flag. Will try to use the So API for the edit.

Comment: What is the difference between dead and rotten links?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Dead is 404,  Not available,  or Moved away like an msdn article form 2006. Rotten is deceptive, crypto, nsfw content, advertising loop, malicous ads.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

359 to go.

Here is the edit link of every post I found and the new Internet archive to Edit:

```
[
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30134952/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/894/adobe-air-and-flex-saving-serialized-objects-to-file"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20502483/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/838/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18967920/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1458/track-page-views-the-smart-way-with-the-impressionist-gem"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26123877/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29877737/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/q/22/how-to-create-reusable-angularjs-directives-that-copy-existing-directives"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20319457/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31077641/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21203007/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18955662/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1387/developing-with-derby-js-installation"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26130572/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19012088/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29364360/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29945763/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1704/2-ways-to-get-started-with-phonegapapache-cordova"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30384667/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1227/blocks-gcd-and-pitfalls-to-avoid"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29606094/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29419365/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/mkuehl",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/Bv1WHnZ"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20087763/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/927/wpf-print-queues-and-capabilities"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20087115/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29041446/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29096626/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1062/wpfs-most-important-property-uselayoutrounding"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19388450/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29946046/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18935927/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/q/22/how-to-create-reusable-angularjs-directives-that-copy-existing-directives"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19006974/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19429563/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298034/converting-writeablebitmap-to-bitmap-in-c-sharp\">here</a> and <a href=\"http://tech.pro/tutorial/654/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19753642/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29666473/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19821714/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29572717/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/846/escaping-curly-braces-in-xaml"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3841018/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20101231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1011/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28968608/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31077727/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31204906/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29228095/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/939/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29770919/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1047/wpf-tutorial-forcing-a-binding-update"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9724721/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20121231000000/http://www.tech.proact.co.uk/emc/emc_celerra_ns-480_nas.htm"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28837369/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19595162/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19417167/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19574401/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19314873/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31084096/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1840/setting-up-git-and-github-from-the-windows-command-prompt"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20212390/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/934/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29538783/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20158562/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1433/performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-four"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28916107/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/2112/scala-tail-recursion-optimisation-and-comparison-to-java"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29454908/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20673007/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30719162/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1262/simplifying-dynamic-positioning-with-jquery-ui"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20153698/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19654021/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30869880/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20689807/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30884924/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1649/very-easy-changelogs-with-git"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20580486/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/981/creating-a-rest-client-using-wcf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21969787/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1491/chat-application-with-signalr-and-aspnet-mvc-4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18766004/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26525915/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying#why_do_i_care_how_is_currying_useful_to_me"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20504568/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26101716/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28836446/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19405022/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21933773/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19032164/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26668544/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1028/wpf-tutorial-binding-to-a-tabcontrol",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1028/wpf-tutorial-binding-to-a-tabcontrol"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26694088/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/752/dotnet-35-adds-named-pipes-support"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27697066/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20920432/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21939941/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28370975/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27473954/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28567087/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/948/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28726037/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26721962/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26755016/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/825/wpf-tutorial-priority-bindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24711361/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26517620/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1149/understanding-method-lookup-in-ruby-20"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26576576/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25296447/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19232138/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/934/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17231750/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18255156/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16060385/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25549827/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25995197/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26025335/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20869286/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/827/csharp-dialogs-part-2-custom-dialogs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26676503/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/838/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27568267/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28626564/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30244194/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20591881/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20760407/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1792/how-to-unit-test-private-functions-in-the-revealing-module-pattern"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28589366/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28610187/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18855835/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21031358/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21044569/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25075414/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30567242/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20150516055057/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21010414/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1281/chroma-key-video-effects-using-javascript-and-the-html5-canvas-element"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30840750/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1473/getting-started-with-angularjs-unit-testing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21293999/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1822/speedtesting-gulp-and-grunt"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30453289/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25548744/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/883/wpf-tutorial-fun-with-markup-extensions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18302072/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1520/partial-function-application-in-python"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31029097/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/881/printing-in-wpf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30802179/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21060733/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1097/simple-chat-nodejs-plus-websockets"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21619188/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30567036/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1252/asynchronous-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30438807/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30964321/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22133462/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/968/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21533281/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1743/javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-lines"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19728843/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21983371/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29731648/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1749/get-your-ci-on-with-travis-ci"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28920082/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/2011/functional-javascript-part-4-function-currying"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29794025/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/790/javascr...in-a-container"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30554900/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20432384/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49075797/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20181231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49075831/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20181231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22122727/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19909895/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1217/the-dos-and-don-ts-of-extension-methods"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12640172/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20121231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20130214003927/http://tech.pro/tutorial/921/combining-images-with-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21746199/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/730/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21669705/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31168919/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30086987/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/q/57/angularjs-unit-testing-using-jasmine-and-resource-backend"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30193713/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22127176/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1763/7-lines-javascript-library-for-calling-asynchronous-functions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29741996/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/948/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13281152/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20121231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1142/building-faceted-search-with-postgresql"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20432243/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20435783/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1649/very-easy-changelogs-with-git"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22160449/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31182186/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22527060/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale#short_and_sweet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30376791/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20722830/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20457976/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/691/csharp-tutorial-font-scaling"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30329898/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/883/wpf-tutorial-fun-with-markup-extensions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23084803/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1146/building-a-shopping-cart-with-signalr-aspnet-web-api-and-knockoutjs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21169312/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22227068/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/656/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20538627/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20072812/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5278144/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20111231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20130928091011/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23115548/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22302574/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20618547/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/786/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23120315/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21878111/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1370/why-collections-should-never-be-null"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21905563/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15902557/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1026/how-to-create-and-populate-a-uitableview"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21885839/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22334514/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14755342/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/914/wcf-callbacks-hanging-wpf-applications"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14794007/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22345162/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14766815/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/971/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23390687/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23378065/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14854842/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21162618/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14606020/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/934/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31058934/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23388306/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15926580/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21803353/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23793678/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14976028/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/654/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23415660/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21902426/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1091/posting-json-data-with-nodejs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14803134/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15104808/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21560235/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/883/wpf-tutorial-fun-with-markup-extensions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15155075/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14961614/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24006828/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24021048/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/653/javascript-interactive-color-picker"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14868939/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14947823/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23789997/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/q/34/using-jsonnet-to-deserialize-incoming-json-in-aspnet-mvc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15041378/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15064862/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15333653/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17278034/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15357939/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15343681/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15399051/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/745/wpf-tutorial-introduction-to-dependency-properties"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23819182/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/780/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18353169/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/822/wpf-tutorial-using-splash-screens-in-sp1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14952724/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14691451/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20130214003927/http://tech.pro/tutorial/921/combining-images-with-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18362169/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15780945/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26145556/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20140809230047/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24806821/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1734/building-decoupled-javascript-applications-with-postaljs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24486307/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1190/package-managers-an-introductory-guide-for-the-uninitiated-front-end-developer#front_end_developers"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24808601/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24816927/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16395775/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1249/modern-emberjs-application-workflow-with-yeoman-and-mocha"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23792989/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23985992/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22228145/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1011/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23151477/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16773185/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15535990/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15561946/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/652/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16401085/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/737/csharp-snippet-tutorial-using-the-filesystemwatcher-class"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24883548/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25139274/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15559675/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15605721/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1149/understanding-method-lookup-in-ruby-20"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24377929/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1554/four-tricks-for-comprehensions-in-python#breaking_the_loop"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23277221/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/615/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-rotate"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15279889/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/650/javascript-draggable-elements"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15279937/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15215888/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1075/javascript-highlighting-selected-text"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14654998/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24459974/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/825/wpf-tutorial-priority-bindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15706850/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25129802/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1213/how-to-build-an-api-with-python-and-flask"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15511768/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15519414/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15555130/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/662/csharp-tutorial-anonymous-delegates-and-scoping"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15202110/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/888/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24752350/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/688/javascript-tutorial-drag-drop-lists"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25090481/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15755320/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15801752/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/939/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17437055/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15429506/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23829601/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15565699/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/656/csharp-creating-rounded-rectangles-using-a-graphics-path"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17452119/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/https://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15057003/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1054/wpf-snippet-tutorial-binding-a-datatable-to-a-datagrid"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23625928/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1433/performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-four"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15435759/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16109202/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1226/basic-rubygem-development"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22732350/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1848/getting-nodejs--sql-server--azure-to-work-together"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15323278/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14674924/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17376355/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/975/building-an-earthquake-monitor-for-iphone-using-mapkit"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22653199/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25379516/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/751/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17558178/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17485239/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22805832/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22924438/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22857616/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26939440/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27001513/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/2131/keeping-angular-service-list-data-in-sync-among-multiple-controllers"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26927109/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15645483/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/791/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15651761/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1148/your-first-rest-service-with-servicestack"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15654517/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27809359/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/743/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27898422/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/830/wpf-tutorial-using-an-itemspanel"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22796760/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17536532/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/743/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27901900/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27029472/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7255037/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20111231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/939/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16146754/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7832797/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20111231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15636201/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/878/csharp-tutorial-asynchronous-stream-operations"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24084324/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1834/working-with-es5-javascript-array-functions-in-modern-and-legacy-browsers#indexof"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16121183/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/931/how-to-build-a-star-ratings-jquery-plugin"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23870353/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1491/chat-application-with-signalr-and-aspnet-mvc-4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55449695/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20191231000000/http://intellitech.pro/tutorial-hadoop-first-lab/",
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20191231000000/http://intellitech.pro/hbase-installation-on-ubuntu/"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23874042/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1227/blocks-gcd-and-pitfalls-to-avoid"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24523736/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15819315/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1189/basics-of-ravendb-nosql"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15825121/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/786/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16781943/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20150502094922/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1156/using-requirejs-in-an-aspnet-mvc-application"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24118037/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25175775/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23919179/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23500706/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/751/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23863639/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/722/flex-tutorial-an-asynchronous-jpeg-encoder"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16315076/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23872128/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16058145/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1165/use-the-jquery-localstorage-and-prefetch-filter-to-optimize-performance"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23919002/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24578275/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24617874/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23909969/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1430/ruby-on-rails-4-authentication-with-facebook-and-omniauth"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24918915/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25675702/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/790/javascript-tutorial-draggable-view-in-a-container"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16455231/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1281/chroma-key-video-effects-using-javascript-and-the-html5-canvas-element"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16456781/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1055/wpf-datagrid-tutorial-row-headers"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16923184/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1146/building-a-shopping-cart-with-signalr-aspnet-web-api-and-knockoutjs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26236153/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25403546/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16165704/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9336956/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20121231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20130921190426/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24977740/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1091/posting-json-data-with-nodejs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26235085/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24298647/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1222/put-the-cloud-to-work-pt-1-create-a-background-worker-using-quartznet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18079385/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/948/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17927611/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18038021/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1453/7-javascript-basics-many-developers-aren-t-using-properly"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16576459/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/780/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25437723/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/895/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17053536/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/968/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17022969/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24647098/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26371533/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26259884/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/930/jquery-custom-tooltips"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17951553/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/664/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26388569/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1091/posting-json-data-with-nodejs"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25452884/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/732/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17663371/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25421951/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1555/10-easy-steps-to-a-complete-understanding-of-sql"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25706239/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27102382/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1075/javascript-highlighting-selected-text"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27205510/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1527/matrix-multiplication-in-functional-javascript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17872621/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1173/the-joy-of-tuples-and-anonymous-types"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27175011/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/907/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25530102/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18536046/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20131217122044/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18552423/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18203018/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/881/printing-in-wpf"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16467937/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1238/angularjs-and-ie8-gotcha-http-delete"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17067025/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/968/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17960337/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1419/10-things-in-sql-server-which-don-t-work-as-expected"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17769918/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1214/javascript-regular-expression-enlightenment"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25447308/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1430/ruby-on-rails-4-authentication-with-facebook-and-omniauth"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25533402/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18618065/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25807792/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/782/getting-image-metadata-with-csharp"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25821466/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1554/four-tricks-for-comprehensions-in-python"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26401484/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/q/1/twitter-bootstrap-css-table-row-cursor-pointer"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25528919/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25505706/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25516922/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/2010/functional-javascript-part-3-apply-call-and-the-arguments-object"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27355156/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1003/wcf-tutorial-serializing-and-transmitting-base-types"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16612943/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1214/javascript-regular-expression-enlightenment"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18627082/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20150316142332/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1520/partial-function-application-in-python"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27363824/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25281246/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25525287/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/857/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25836286/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27373698/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20150430043510/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1240/datetimeoffset--what-time-is-it"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46589908/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20171231000000/http://web.archive.org/web/20131217122044/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28073361/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/696/csharp-tutorial-event-accessors"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26479245/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1238/angularjs-and-ie8-gotcha-http-delete"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28074592/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/652/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28339537/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1191/say-no-to-the-repository-pattern-in-your-dal"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26479451/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1187/creating-a-c-fluent-api"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28022689/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1101/generic-method-to-safely-perform-cross-thread-"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28236941/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20151231000000/http://tech.pro/blog/1917/a-better-query-language-bql-language-specification"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55642404/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20191231000000/https://web.archive.org/web/20141027055124/http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25876685/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1992/basics-of-curl"
    ]
  },
  {
    "EditLink": "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18676214/edit",
    "ArchiveLink": [
      "https://web.archive.org/web/20131231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: ~60 false positive removed.

Comment: Did 3 random links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23626084) - [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23626595) - [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23626596))