# Links to torrent sites

Tags: discussion, questions

This [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9340741) slipped through the review process, but the original author quickly reverted the change.

The site was also linked [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320463/xcode-6-3-not-running-ios-8-4-update-to-6-4-fails/31320577#comment52485615_31320577).

Should the comment be flagged?

**Update:**

The comment has been deleted.

Comment: The torrent links seems to not be listed in the [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).... Which, to me, says that it's not forbidden here - even if I don't like such link

Comment: @Thomas: See Copyright section.

Comment: @nhahtdh `users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it` => this is not what he did, right?

Comment: @Thomas: XCode is owned by Apple, and I don't think the person who suggest that edit has any rights to distribute the file.

Comment: @nhahtdh I won't comment about the torrent link since it's been removed, but the [file is open to anyone who has Apple ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-and-get-the-dmg-file). (personally, I certainly prefer official sites than torrent site though)

Comment: @AndrewT.: I'm only commenting about the torrent link, since it's what this question is about...

Comment: @AndrewT. It can be downloaded by anyone, but AFAIK it is not redistributable.

Comment: If the content on the torrent page is illegal, then you might have a case. But **torrents are not illegal** and are a perfectly acceptable way to distribute files. Many open source projects are distributed via torrent and a good number of modern games use p2p to save on patching bandwith.

Comment: @slicedtoad I hear you and agree that there are valid uses for them.  But in this case, isn't there more of a concern about downloading a commercial and/or licensed product from a suspicious site?  Not a lawyer.  Purely cautious about links and/or malware. :)

Comment: On a legal standing, it has been shown in some countries that linking to torrent sites can actually get your site in turn banned, this has happened a few times in the UK on a petty scale. So even if it is not illegal per se we should probably ban torrent site links on here I think

Comment: @slicedtoad: Torrent protocol is not illegal, but the fact that the person who distribute the XCode installation file doesn't have the distribution rights makes it illegal.

Comment: @nhahtdh Right, provided it's it's not redistributable. Do you happen to have a link to the xcode license agreement? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @slicedtoad: https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf Section 2b

Comment: " You may not rent, lease, lend, sell, sublicense
or otherwise redistribute the Developer Software or exploit any services provided by or through
the Developer Software in any unauthorized way. "

Comment: @PetahChristian: whilst it doesn't matter so much here on _Meta_, it's worth me pointing out that (a) answers to questions don't belong in questions as edits, and (b) in the event you _have_ to put it in the question (e.g. because the question has been closed) please put it at the end, so that the question reads normally. Putting it at the start makes the question hard to read for readers who did not see the original (i.e. most readers). Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't see why the comment should be flagged (I'm guessing the now deleted comment contained a link to some torrent site). On what basis would you flag the comment?

If something is indeed not legal (as [the answerer above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303836/508666) states) there are processes in place to handle it. Considering Stack Exchange is a company in the USA the DMCA process would probably be used for this.

It is not up to users (or mods for that matter) to judge whether content is indeed not legal. I assume here that meskobalazs is neither a lawyer nor an owner of said IP so his statement about it being "not exactly legal" is as good as my statement saying it is totally legal.

So no: there is imo no reason to flag comments like that.

YMMV, IANAL, BBQ

Comment: This might not be a valid (authentic) version of software.  Surely there's a difference between linking to Apple's download site, and a questionable or suspicious site.  Maybe the download is fine.  Maybe it's been tampered with and has a virus. Maybe it's been repackaged and doesn't properly work.  Who knows?  But we should agree that it's less likely that Apple's download has been altered or tampered with.

Comment: Sure it might not be valid. But it might as well be very much valid. The point of my post is that we simply just don't know and as such we cannot and should not judge the content. That is exactly what the DMCA is about.

Comment: In short, we should not flag it because it's not our problem.  It's Apple's problem, or perhaps some user's problem.  Let them deal with it.  In effect, the argument is that we're not responsible.

Comment: I think the point is, users to StackOverflow, especially those new to the site/programming, expect some level of validity and safety with links. Someone suggests to download a library from source? Then it _must_ be okay. Sure, the legality of a link differs across the world, but even legal links are unsafe or unreliable (hint, SourceForge). For example, if I see someone post a link from dropbox, I suggest they use Imgur or something else -- I do not trust personal document links from people I do not know.

Comment: @Hunter: There are other reasons why one should avoid putting images used on a SE site anywhere but on SE's imgur account. See [Ban ImageShack Images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300232)