# Are Stack Overflow images deleted after time?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images, opera

I was just referencing one of mine [older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21884021/2521214) and spotted that one image is missing (only the image icon there instead). I use only the SO add image icon for adding images so it is stored on `i.stack.imgur.com` and the image in question is this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySLyp.png]

The second image in the same answer is still OK but most likely it was added later. So my question is:

**What are the reasons for SO image deletion?**

- Are the images being deleted after some time
- or based on usage (no views for some time,no reference to it)?
- or this was a bug related deletion?

I am a heavy image user and referencing my older Answers a lot so this could be a problem for me.

I am aware of this [Ban ImageShack Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300232/2521214) but as I mentioned I use only SO internal image storage so that is not the case.

**PS.**

Luckily I still have the image on my hard drive so Here it is if it helps to resolve the issue.

[image: again uploaded image]

I will change the image in the answer after this is resolved (to not broke something needed to recognize what has been happening there)

**[Edit2] as some of you can see the image in question**

Then this is something entirely different then deletion. It is Browser related issue I use:

```
Opera Version: 36.0.2130.32 (which is just skinned chrome as Opera does not exist anymore)
```

If I use **IE** or **real Opera** (`Opera 12.10`) instead the image is loading properly.

Clearing browser info and/or restarting does not help. It may be **Opera related bug on the browser side**. If I find out more info will update this post anyway thanks for your support and answers.

**[Edit3] Looks like I finally found out the solution**

In Opera settings un-checking these optoins solved the problem

[image: solution]

Comment: I see both images on the answer and on this question.

Comment: @Oded then may be it is something completely different, one or two days ago I was seeing the same behavior on one low quality question and after uploading again the images where visible

Comment: That could be just a problem on the imgur side - an image failed to load?

Comment: Can't repro on Opera 35 either ;)

Comment: @Oded Just tried IE and there it is loading properly so what is wrong With my Opera? any hints what to do?

Comment: Huh. Clear you cache? Could be that a bad cached version is living in the browser cache.

Comment: @Oded didn't help

Comment: Strange - perhaps enable the dev tools and take a look at them? Might report an error that will give us a clue...

Comment: @Oded I am no Web/html programmer but the log is empty (no errors I can see). If I click on the Image link the page is blank has header,body and tags but no image (not even blank one) and again no errors

Comment: It could be a badly cached version in a proxy somewhere (though, if loads in IE... that seems to rule it out). I don't have an answer for you, except that it looks like a problem specific to your and the browser :(

Comment: @Oded Yeah seems like it. Thanks for your help anyway (may be in time some update will solve it ... or mess it up completely).

Comment: @Oded Today I was not seeing even newly added images not just the old ones so I dig deeper into Opera settings and found out the solution (at least all the images I tried are visible now) see Edit3

Comment: Oh wow. You may want to report that to Opera - looks like a bug there

Answer (score 8):

First - I can't reproduce the issue. I see both images on the old answer and here.

---

Images stored on `i.stack.imgur.com` are not normally deleted (more on this below). This is under an agreement we have with imgur - that URL and servers are not under normal imgur terms and conditions.

On rare occasions we will delete an image from imgur - if we got a valid DMCA takedown notice which requires us to remove it, we will. Additionally, if an image contains sensitive information (personally identifying information, passwords etc...) it may also be removed.

There is no general image removal rule - time based or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Imgur keep images for ever as long as they are receiving at least 1 view every six months. If they are not they may be deleted to save space. Popular images and those shared on Imgur will probably meet this criteria due to becoming viral and being better accessible.

As of February 2015, Imgur states that images are never deleted unless requested.

Comment: it was answered `Feb 19 '14 at 14:51` so it could be the case but The question is when it got deleted I am pretty sure in 2015 the image was still there and both images were added +/- few days tops and from there they share the views so in that case both images would be deleted not just one

Comment: As per @Oded's answer, this is irrelevant because Stack Overflow has an agreement with Imgur that is different than their standard T&C.